# Placing the button in my page

Tags: html, css, button, margin

Actually I'm new to web designing and I'm going to make my own social network and I'm using the amazing layout of [Angelsmood.com music social network](http://www.angelsmood.com/videochannel/).

Everything is OK with designing except that I can't place the "Sign Up" button on the right place; it has a lot of margin on its right side. The problem is that there's no margin in my CSS code. Here's my code:

```
<div id="header_register">                  
    <a href="~/register/">Sign Up</a> 

    <div>
    Artists and their true fans are human angels.
    Find them, connect with them and become one of them.
    </div>

</div>
```

And Here's the CSS:

```
#header_register {
position: relative;
font-size: 12px;
}

#header_register a {
display: block;
height: 30px;
line-height: 30px;
background: ##810101;
color: #fff;
font-weight: bold;
font-size: 14px;
float: left;
text-decoration: none;
border: 1px #508F54 solid;
}
```

Please help me to fix this.

Comment: Please post a jsfiddle ( jsfiddle.net ) of the problem so that it is easier to spot the problem.

Comment: I think you forgot your CSS.

Comment: *"The problem is that there's no margin in my CSS code."*. Still should post it. Better yet to a fiddle

Comment: I added the css. Please recheck it.

Comment: You are floating the Sign up button to the left

Comment: Based on your code ([see this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a3xda/)), I am struggling to see any margin on the right like you describe. In fact it looks as if there is *0 margin* on the right. Are you sure it's not other CSS or any inline styling that is causing this?

Comment: [try this](http://jsfiddle.net/shyamn/a3xda/1/)

Answer (score 0):

I made a fiddle and tried to fix your problem the best I could based on the information you gave us.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xj8m3/)

Things I did...  took your `line-height` out and moved the link after the div so you didn't have to use it... then I `margin: 0 auto` to center the `<a>` tag.

Instead of `float: left;`

I took it out added a `width` of the `<a>` tag so it did not span the width of the screen.

If you need this to function in a different way that I have illustrated ask and I will show you on the fiddle I posted.